# No Display Templates for Popular Items web part from Search-Driven Content category

Tags: feature, sharepoint-server, display-template, content-search-web-part

I have a Popular Items WebPart on my site and in the Display Templates these things are selected:

[image]

I have saved this site as template, via **Save Site as Template** option, and created a new site from this template, and I have an issue with the Popular Items WebPart on that site, because in the Control and Item field in the Display Templates sections I see only one option **External Template Reference**, so I cannot select List for a Control field and Two lines for the Item field:

[image]

I see Display Templates in the **masterpagegallery** on both sites and I even tried to activate **Search Server Web Parts and Templates** site collection feature, but it didn't help.

Anybody knows why I have this issue with the Display Templates?
Thanks in advance!

Update:
I still didn't find how to make it work. I see Display Templates in the Master Page Gallery, but I do not see them as option in the Display Templates section of the Popular Items WebPart.

Comment: what version of SharePoint are you using? On premise 2013, 2016 or SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try downloading the .html file to disk, deleting the .html and .js file then re-uploading the .html and re-publishing a major version to get SharePoint to create the .js files.

I see the (External Template Reference) being shown when only the .js file exists and no corresponding .html display template has been uploaded. Deploying only the .js file is legitimate but it does mean the SharePoint UI user cannot use the CSWP Edit Web Part Properties to change to any custom templates that do not have .html files.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Craig